# How do I find the upper bound of the sequence $\left(a_n\right)_n$ with $a_n=\frac{2n}{1+n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I recently started to study sequences and series in calculus and studied the concept of bounded sequences. In the following seuquence: $\left(a_n\right)_n$ with $a_n=\frac{2n}{1+n}$

I can see clearly that the lower bound is 1. But I am perplexed when it comes to finding the upper bound.

I can't plug in infinity because I would get infinity over infinity. So I try to apply L'Hopital's rule and I find that the derivative of the numerator over derivative of the denominator is 2.

Is this enough to conclude that the upper bound is 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bit more. That the limit of the sequence is $2$ isn't enough. You also need, that this sequence is monotonous. Then you can say that $2$ is the upper bound.

You can try it this way:

As $n$ approaches infinity, you see that $n$ gets much bigger than 1, so you can neglect it and you get
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{2n}{1+n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2n}{n} = 2. $$

Because $a_n$ is monotonous, you see, that this is indeed the upper bound.

Comment: Ok, got it! and one more question. To find the lower bound should I check for n=0 or n=1?

Comment: You can also apply l'Hospital if denominator approach to infinity. So both your and Reboot's approach show that $\lim a_n = 2$. But that doesn't imply that upper bound is 2. That comes from $\frac{2n}{n + 1} ≤ \frac{2n}{n} = 2$. The limit shows that it's the least upper bound.

Comment: @Reboot_87 Well, you can see, that $a_n$ is always non-negative and monotonous. So you should check the smallest $n$, which would be $n=0$.

Comment: @Reboot_87 Are you familiar with the monotone convergence theorem? *A sequence that is monotonically increasing converges* if and only if *it is bounded above and, in this case* $\lim a_n = \sup (a_n) $. The important part here is the forwards implication

Comment: @user87690 Oh, I forgot that. I'll edit it.

Comment: just because a sequence converges to a number doesnt mean that number is an upper bound to the sequence. Just saying.

Comment: @GPerez. I did not know this theorem. The one I just learned states that: a sequence that is monotonic (either increasing or decreasind) and is bounded is convergent.

Comment: @mathemagician Doesn't it? Even if it monotonically increases? I'm pretty sure it does, though I could be rusty

Comment: it needs to be monotonically increasing and bounded to converge in R

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it it easily shown that the sequence is monotonically increasing. As a consequence, if it converges, It's upper bound is identified with the limit.

Given that you calculate:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}(2n)}{\frac{1}{n}(1+n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2}{\frac{1}{n}+1}=\frac{2}{0+1}=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Alex R:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n}{1+n} \stackrel {\text{*}}= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{\frac1n+1} = 2.$$

*Divide and multiply by $n$

Also, in general, L'Hôpital is kind of over the top for these kinds of limits. Try proving that, for any rational limit (quotient of polynomials):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_qn^q+a_{q-1}n^{q-1}+\dots+a_1n+a_0}{b_pn^p+b_{p-1}n^{p-1}+\dots+b_1n+b_0}=\left\{\begin{array} {r} 0,  \quad p>q \\ \infty, \quad p<q \\ \frac{a_q}{b_p}, \quad p=q \end{array}\right.$$